# Match a variable against second level in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, search

I‘m trying to simplify my iteration through the second level of a dictionary.

I know this works for simple lists:

```
if new not in existing_list:
    dosomestuff
```

Is there any chance to do something similar for a dictionary `y` where each entry looks like this?

```
{'fields':
    {'ID': 123, 'name': 'test'},
 'otherfield': 'value'
}
```

What I need to do is to compare a variable (let‘s called it `x`) against each `y['fields']['ID']`. Currently I‘m just iterating through `y` but I thought there must be a smarter way to find a match.

Comment: Nope, you've got to iterate over it yourself.

Comment: Serialize your dictionary to a string with `json.dumps()` and use RegEx to find the substring in the string

Answer (score 1):

Why not create the dictionary with ID as the key?

```
d = {143:
         {‘name‘: ‘test'},
     545:
         {'name': 'another test'},
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create the illusion that you are doing it like the list but you have to iterate through dict values. Here is one way to do it.

```
mydict = {'fields': {'id': 123, 'name': 'value'}, 'fields2': 'test'}

test_id = 123

if test_id in (level2['id'] for level2 in mydict.values()):
    print("success: value found")
else:
    print("The value does not exist")
# Output: success: value found
```

Answer (score 1):

To detect in 1 line if there is an inner_value by the given inner_key, try this:

```
my_dict= {'fields': {'ID': 123, 'name': 'test'},
          'otherfield': 'value'}

inner_key, inner_value = 'ID', 123

print(inner_value in [val.get(inner_key) for val in my_dict.values() if isinstance(val, dict)])
# True
```

Note, that the `get()` method will safe you from crash if inner_key is not in the inner dict;
and the `isinstance()` function - if there are not only dicts in the my_dict.values().

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking of using list comprehension to explore the dictionary and build a list of each relevant field to look for, like `['fields']['ID']`, and then use the `if x in list` you already mentioned. This is simple, easily readable and can be adjusted to cover different fields with minimal modifications.

```
>>> MyDict = {}
>>> MyDict["entry1"] = {'fields':{'ID': 123, 'name': 'test'},'otherfield': 'value' }
>>> MyDict["entry2"] = {'fields':{'ID': 456, 'name': 'test2'},'otherfield': 'value2' }
>>> x = 123
>>> if x in [v['fields']['ID'] for v in MyDict.values()]:
...   print("found x")
...
found x
>>> x = 789
>>> if x in [v['fields']['ID'] for v in MyDict.values()]:
...   print("found x")
...
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `'ID'` a list? What about:

```
dictionary = {'fields':
    {'ID': [123,456], 'name': 'test'},
    'otherfield': 'value'}
item = 789
if item != dictionary['fields']['ID']:
    print('Hurra!')
```

Or use another comparison method for different data types.

*And if you don't know which first level field you need:*

```
if item not in (dictionary[field]['ID'] for field in dictionary.keys()):
    print('Hurra!')
```

Answer (score 0):

Others have provided some good options so I figured I'd list something different you may choose to use:

(reusing User's example)

```
>>> MyDict = {}
>>> MyDict["entry1"] = {'fields':{'ID': 123, 'name': 'test'},'otherfield': 'value' }
>>> MyDict["entry2"] = {'fields':{'ID': 456, 'name': 'test2'},'otherfield': 'value2' }
>>> for v in map(lambda x: x['ID'], 
                 filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, dict) and 'ID' in x,
                        sum(map(lambda x:list(x.values()),
                                list(MyDict.values())), 
                            []))):
...     v
...
123
456
```

To explain this, moving from the innermost function outward:

1. innermost map creates a list of N entries, where N is number of
       items in top level dict and each entry is a list of the values of
       each item in the dict format you've shown above. Thus, a list of
       list.
2. Sum a list of list into a single list
3. Filter list for dicts with 'ID' key
4. Obtain only the 'ID' value from each such dict